# How to validate only mandatory fields in jQuery validation plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, jquery-validation-engine

Validate only mandatory fields in jQuery validation plugin: below is my code

```
<label for="firstName">First Name<span class="required">*</span></label>
<input type="text" id="firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="firstName">
<label for="address1">Address Line 1</label>
<input type="text" id="address1" class="form-control" placeholder="Address Line 1" name="address1">
```

I want to skip address 1 on form submit

Comment: Can you show your jQuery code?

Comment: $('#profileDetailsPage').validate({
     
    rules: {
     firstName:{required: true,textonly: true},
     address1:{required: true,textonly: true}
     
    },
    messages: {
     firstname: "Please enter your first name",
     address1:"Please enter only text"
    },
    submitHandler: function() {}
    });

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `required` flag to `false` for `address1`.

```
$('#profileDetailsPage').validate({
    rules: {
        firstName:{
            required: true,
            textonly: true
        },
        address1:{
            required: false, // don't require this field
            textonly: true
        }
    },
    messages: {
        firstname: "Please enter your first name",
        address1: "Please enter only text"
    },
    submitHandler: function() {}
});
```

Comment: If do like this on submit the form does not validates, just returns:
?title=&firstName=&lastName=&houseNo=&postalCode=&address1=&address2=&townCity=&country=&mobileNo=